# Is there an intuitive explanation as to why the de Broglie wavelength is inversely proportional to the particle's momentum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, wavelength, wave-particle-duality

Is there an **intuitive** explanation as to why the de Broglie wavelength of a particle (say a photon) is inversely proportional to its momentum? It can be shown, mathematically, that:

$$E = h\dfrac{c}{\lambda}$$
$$E^2=(mc^2)^2+(pc)^2$$
$$E_{\text{photon}}^2 = (pc)^2$$
$$h\dfrac{c}{\lambda} = pc$$
$$\therefore \boxed{\frac{h}{\lambda} = p}$$

However, I fail to conceptually understand why this is the case. Why is $p$ $\propto$ $\dfrac{1}{\lambda}$?

---

For some context, I'm a high school student with only a superficial understanding of quantum mechanics or calculus, but answers of every level are more than welcome.

Comment: My answer (linked at the end of this comment) probably assumes more background than you have right now, but I'm mot sure it can be made much simpler:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/197673/4993

Comment: [The more general uncertainty principle, beyond quantum](https://www.3blue1brown.com/lessons/uncertainty-principle)

Comment: Well, if you accept that a photon's energy scales with wavelength, it would seem reasonable to define a momentum which also scales with wavelength.  This is analogous to the classical mechanics  $p = m*v$  and $KE = \frac{m*v^2}{2}$ , both of which scale with speed.